# How do I duck and run?

Tags: the-last-of-us

Is it possible to run (faster) while crouching?

My character moves quite slowly when crouched, and stands up when running. But my companions seem to be able to do both at the same time.

Maybe I missed that part in the tutorial, or is it just not possible for the player?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope you cannot perform that move, there's no roadie run ala Gears of War available, I'm afraid.

Helpful links [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/652686-the-last-of-us/66464064) and [here](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/The-Last-of-Us-General/Did-they-take-out-Crouch-Sprinting/td-p/40411855)

Answer (score 0):

You can use perks that enhance the speed of crouched movement

[Agility](http://thelastofus.wikia.com/wiki/Agility)

- Level 1 - Crouch walk very quickly
- Level 2 - You are nearly impossible to hear while moving. Walk, climb and crouch walk very quickly.

[Sharp Ears](http://thelastofus.wikia.com/wiki/Sharp_Ears)

- Level 3 - Enter listen mode more quickly, you do not slow down while crouch-walking in listen mode, the meter regenerates 30% faster, and stay in listen mode 30% longer

Answer (score 0):

There can be a solution to the slow crouch-walk. If you are crouching, and want to quickly move away from the current place, just sprint away to another hiding spot. This is not very effective against clickers, though.